# Angular material2 dialog (mat-dialog) scroll page to top when click on close.

Tags: angular, angular-material2

When ever I click on the close button in mat-dialog, the scroll top position automatically reset and move to top. I am using angular material 6.1.0 version.  This is happening only in IE11.

Comment: please share some code here

Comment: I was observing the same bug in Angular2 material v1.1.4, but it [was solved in 1.1.5](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10897).

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue with Angular material 7.3.2.
When the dialog close the page scroll up. unless if I click on an element in the page then open the dialog.
later, I found out that the issue is happening because there is a focused element at the top of the page (navigation button) and clicking on an element on the page removes the focus from that button.

so I added `autoFocus: true` and `restoreFocus: false` to the config object of the matdialog open method

Comment: Observed that issue just now (4 years later) and your solution works!